# Cocoa Data Binding - One view object bound to two 'enabled' properties

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Using Cocoa Data Binding I have bound a button's 'enabled' property to two separate 'Model Key Paths' (**Enabled** and **Enabled2**).

The idea is that the button will become enabled if *either* of these properties is true.

Unfortunately, it only works if *both* become true.

Can anyone help me change this logic from *AND* to *OR*?

Comment: I don't think Boole lets us use the NSNegateBoolean value transformer to get what you need, because the AND is baked into the NSButton bindings.  So you may have to create a readonly property with dependent keypaths that returns the OR, and bind to just that.

Answer (score 0):

Cool question-- I'm going to make a shot in the dark, I can't confirm it for you until tomorrow, but try this maybe?

Create a new property, `enabledOrEnabled2` (maybe with a better name).
Override the getter (`-(BOOL)enabledOrEnabled2`) for this property,
to just return `(Enabled || Enabled2)`

Set the Key Path to be `enabledOrEnabled2`

I'm a little skeptical if this will work because Cocoa Bindings work by using KVC and KVO.  So atm, your view controller is observing your `Enabled` and `Enabled2` properties.  What happens during runtime is that Cocoa will override your properties w/ their own KVO properties that look and act just like you think they would.  Except the setters have been overridden, to send out notifications to observers.

I think the problem with my solution is that `-(void)setEnabledOrEnabled2` will never be called, because you will only be setting your `Enabled` and `Enabled2` properties.  Therefore, the Cocoa overridden `-(void)setEnabledOrEnabled2` will never notify your observing view controller

**EDIT:** Just read @stevesilva's comment, and didn't even know that [dependent keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html) was a thing.  Looks like you could definitely implement it this way if you wanted to

Actually, a first-thought hack would be to switch from overriding the getter (like I first recommended), and instead override the setters: `-(void)setEnabled` and `-(void)setEnabled2`, and add a line, something like: `_enabledOrEnabled2 = _Enabled || _Enabled2`.  That way anytime you set your two BOOL properties, it will update `enabledOrEnabled2`, which will then send a notification out to it's observer, your view controller.

But now that I've written that out, I was wondering about the second part of Cocoa Bindings, KVC to modify the model whenever the view sees changes.

And because you are actually using Bindings on an `Enabled` state-- I actually don't think you should be using Bindings.  This is because the view can't actually be modified (i.e, you can't modify the `enabled` state of a button).  So you wouldn't ever need to use KVC to change `enabledOrEnabled2`, you only need your button to observe BOOLs to know if it should be enabled or not.

So scrap everything I said thusfar--
What you **should** do is still modify the setters ( `-(void)setEnabled` and `-(void)setEnabled2` ), and before setting the ivar you should add a line:
`[self.button setEnabled:(_Enabled || _Enabled2)];`

That should do the trick for ya :)

Sorry for rambling a bit, I feel like the info I wrote initially may be helpful so I decided not to delete it

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Steve and Matty. In the end I solved this by creating a property just for the button's enabled state and then put the logic as to when this gets set in the View Controller code. It meant creating an extra property but simplifies things.

Comment: Not a problem :) If you wouldn't mind, could you edit with your code?  I'd like to see what worked for you

Comment: @MattyAyOh - with dependent keypaths, it's two one-line methods...  the getter for the ORed property, and the method for registering the dependent keypaths.  To pimp my [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463979/itunes-like-count-buttons-using-cocoa-bindings/24471002#24471002), it is a fantastically slick way to avoid registering observers.