# Is it possible to use cocoa bindings with NSTableView and Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I'd like to know is it possible to use cocoa bindings to show one-to-many or many-to-many relationships on NSTableView row.

What I'm trying to do is show one entity per row and in one column I'd like to show thru relationship more than one attributes from another entity.

Currently my schema is something like this:

Person <--->> tag

One row should look like this:

```
Name | Birth   | Address    | tag
--------------------------------------------------------
jon   75/12/13   123 street   handyman, contractor
paul  53/03/20   53 avenue 1  contractor, swimmer, biologist
```

is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. For purposes of discussion, I'll assume a collection property `tags` for the one-to-many relationship.

You can make a dependent property which is the tag list string:

```
+ (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTagList
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"tags"];
}
- (NSString*) tagList
{
    return [[self.tags sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
}
```

(If `tags` is a set rather than an array, you'd use `self.tags.allObjects`.)

Since this is sort of specific to how the tag list is presented in a view, it can be considered more part of the view layer than the model layer. Therefore, you might define these methods in a category on your class, rather than the class itself.

Another approach is to do the same thing using a value transformer class. You'd bind the text field to the `tags` collection property but specify the name of a custom value transformer class. That class would transform from the collection class (array or set) and produce a string in a manner similar to the above.

```
@interface TagListTransformer : NSValueTransformer {}
@end

@implementation TagListTransformer

+ (Class) transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSString class];
}

+ (BOOL) allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return NO;
}

- (id) transformedValue:(id)value
{
    return [[value sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
}

@end
```

Comment: Note: the tag list isn't automatically refreshed when the name of a tag changes.

Comment: @Willeke, in which sense? The tag list is recreated every time it's asked for. The `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingTagList` method ensures that KVO knows that change notifications need to be emitted for `tagList` whenever `tags` changes in a KVO-compliant manner. With the value transformer, the binding is observing `tags` directly and, when it changes, the bound view will update itself and use the transformer to get the tag list, which will be up-to-date.

Comment: Sorry, I'm thinking one step too far. It will work if tags is an array of strings. I did too much Core Data I think.

Comment: @Willeke may be thinking of situations where the "tag" is an entity and the string is a property of that entity.  If you needed to display several `tag.nameString` within `tagList`, then you get into [workarounds like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463979/itunes-like-count-buttons-using-cocoa-bindings/), where I just say, to hell with KVO, and have the `tag` object call `setTagList` on the parent to force recalculation of `tagList` when the `nameString` property changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up to create NSValueTransformer class. It worked just as expected.