# CoreData: Key-Value Observing relationship NSSet element's attributes

Tags: core-data, key-value-observing, nsoutlineview

I have a `Garage` entity which contains several `Car` (one-to-many relationship).
A car has a `price: NSNumber` attribute.

I display the data in a NSOutlineView via a NSTreeController.
A group row represents a `Garage` with a label whose value is the total value of all the cars in the garage.

A row inside a group represents a single car.

When I change the price (by editing or clicking a button) of a car, the car row is updated, but not the garage group row. BUT when I add or remove a car, the total value in the garage row gets updated.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Garage: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var cars: NSSet?    

    public override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        let mutableSet = NSMutableSet(set: super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key))
        if key == "totalValueGarage" {
            mutableSet.add("cars")
        }
        return mutableSet as! Set<String>
    }
}
    /// Total value of the garage. Bound to the NSOutlineView group row.
    @objc dynamic var totalValue: NSNumber {
        var toReturn: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: 0.0)
        if let cars = self.cars {
            for case let car in cars {
                toReturn = NSNumber(value: (toReturn.doubleValue + car.price.doubleValue))               
            }
        }
        return toReturn
    }
```

```
public class Car: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var price: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged public var garage: Garage?

    public override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        let mutableSet = NSMutableSet(set: super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key))
        if key == "price" {
            mutableSet.add("garage") // Let the system know that garage is affected by the price value
        }
        return mutableSet as! Set<String>
    }

}
```

How can I make sure that the group rows of the OutlineView are updated when I change the price of a car ?

**What I tried**

- Manually calling garage.willChangeValueForKey("cars") and garage.willChangeValueForKey("cars"). This is ugly, and undoing changes won't propagate changes. I would have to trigger these notifications when undoing as well.
- Calling outlineView.reloadItem(item: Any?) but it won't work. Besides, it's not as elegant as using KVO.

Thanks for your advice!!

Comment: I ended up [having the child object call a setter on the parent to trigger KVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463979/itunes-like-count-buttons-using-cocoa-bindings/24471002#24471002).   I wanted to avoid having the parent have to programatically observe each child.  Instead each child knows its parent and can trigger a recalculation just by calling a (phony) setter on the parent.